# Primefaces with <t:documentHead/>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces, tomahawk

Primefaces only includes their scripts and style when it finds a  tag.

I want to use  due to general performance tuning suggested on this link:
http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Performance

Are there any alternative to include Primefaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

You can include the PrimeFaces css and js manually in your base pages (or on every page if u want manually) - however this wont stop primefaces from also injecting itself.

There is no 'manual' way to stop primefaces injecting itself into the head with out renderer interventions - ie: create your own renderkit overwrite there 'head' renderer and comment out the part that includes there scripts.